# Getting the highest value of a Status

Tags: sql, teradata

Teradata query looks like this:

```
Select
a,
b,
MIN(Record_Start_Date) as MIN_Record_Start_Date,
MAX(Record_End_Date) as MAX_Record_End_Date
FROM tbl
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Now I would like to add a third attribute "status". Problem is - I want only the "last" status - the value of a row with the highest value of "Record_End_Date".

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Isn't `max(Record_End_Date)` working on teradata?

Comment: I want the value of STATUS column - the one value where Record_End_Date = MAX(Record_End_Date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to an OLAP function instead of an aggregate:

```
SELECT
   a,
   b,
MIN(Record_Start_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY a, b) AS  MIN_Record_Start_Date,
Record_End_Date AS MAX_Record_End_Date,
Status
FROM tbl
QUALIFY 
   ROW_NUMBER() 
   OVER (PARTITION BY a,b 
         ORDER BY Record_End_date DESC) = 1
```